# What does it mean attempted relative import beyond top-level package?

Tags: django

Traceback

```
    File "", line 5, in <module>
    from ..books.models import Commen
    ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

forms.py

```
from ..books.models import Comment
```

Maybe problem in urls.py?

There is the structure of my project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPZ3Y.png)

Comment: Why not import it with `from books.models import Comment`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem cuz this forms.py from another app

Comment: exactly, and the python root is the directory immediately above the apps, so you import it with `from appname.models import Comment`, here thus `books.models`.

Comment: of course you replace `appname` with `books`.